# Oracle ADF. Происходит отключение бд при загрузке blob больше 1МБ

Tags: java, blob, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

> Jdeveloper version 12.2.1.3.0
>
> WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0
>
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
>   Production

Добрый день, при загрузке blob в бд, после вызова комита теряется соединение

Мой атрибут в Entity и код:

```
<Attribute
  Name="FilterProdValue"
  IsQueriable="false"
  ColumnName="FILTER_PROD_VALUE"
  SQLType="BLOB"
  Type="oracle.jbo.domain.BlobDomain"
  ColumnType="BLOB"
  TableName="ANALYSIS_FILTER"/>
```

Java код:

ApplicationModule am =

```
ADFUtils.getApplicationModuleForDataControl("AppModuleDataControl");
ViewObject vo = am.findViewObject("AnalysisFilterView1");
AnalysisFilterViewRowImpl newRow = (AnalysisFilterViewRowImpl) vo.createRow();

//код работы с blob

BlobDomain blob = new BlobDomain();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

oos.writeObject(prodTreeModel.getWrappedData()); // prodTreeModel  - custom class with hierarchical data

oos.flush();
oos.close();

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
OutputStream out = null;

try {

  out = blob.getBinaryOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

  for (int length; (length = in.read(buffer)) > -1;) {

      out.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }

  in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

  e.printStackTrace();
}

out.close();

newRow.setFilterProdValue(blob);
```

Возвращаются следующие ошибки:

```
<oracle.adf.model> <OracleSQLBuilderImpl> <bindWhereAttrValue> <[123090] Where binding param 1: test>

<oracle.adf.model> <EntityImpl> <compare> <[123091] Entity compare failed for attribute FilterProdValue>

<oracle.adf.model> <EntityImpl> <compare> <[123092] Difference in lob values for attribute at index:1>

<oracle.adf.model> <EntityImpl> <doDMLWithLOBs> <[123093] EntityImpl.doDMLWithBlob failed...>

<oracle.adf.model> <EntityImpl> <doDMLWithLOBs> <[123094] oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-29000: Перехвачено непредвиденное исключение: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException, сообщ.=Ошибка ввода/вывода: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

at oracle.jbo.domain.BlobDomain.writeBytesToLob(BlobDomain.java:464)

at oracle.jbo.domain.BaseLobDomain.saveToDatabase(BaseLobDomain.java:624)
```

Просьба помочь!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the same exception is registered on Metalink:
Connection Reset By Peer When Doing A Query On A BLOB

There are the same lines of code, from issue became:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.putBytes(T4CConnection.java:3097)
at oracle.sql.BLOB.setBytes(BLOB.java:803)
```

So, i think that you must forward your DBA to this bugs:

- Bug 27881955 - java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer Error Code
- Bug 27901292 - CAUSED BY: JAVA.IO.IOEXCEPTION: CONNECTION RESET BY PEER

And as a workaround oracle reccomend use this settings.
Use the following Java arguments as a workaround:

`-Doracle.net.useZeroCopyIO=false
-Doracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=1800 (n is in milliseconds)
-Doracle.net.keepAlive=true`

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно было
-Doracle.net.useZeroCopyIO=false